# Android Two-way data binding AdapterViewBindingAdapter (ListView)

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a `ListView` and trying to use two-way data binding to set the `selectedItemPosition` in a ViewModel using [Two-Way Attributes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-attributes)

But the problem is it doesn't work, the selected item doesn't set in the Value of the liveData, I tried to observe it and the value never changes when i select an item in the `listView`

data binding in XML:

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            tools:listheader="@tools:sample/lorem"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewModel.chosenPosition}" />
```

in the ViewModel:

```
   val chosenPosition = MutableLiveData<Int>()
```

in the Fragment:

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

binding.teamsListView.adapter = ArrayAdapter(
                context,
                R.layout.list_item_choice, teamsNames
            )

viewModel.chosenPosition.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        Timber.d("chosen position = $it") //never triggers when I select an item in the ListView 
    }
```

Comment: How do you change the `viewModel.chosenPosition`?

Comment: by selecting an item in listview it should set the value by databinding `android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewModel.chosenPosition}"`

Comment: From where did you come up with this attribute? Do you have a BindingAdapter?

Comment: @Zain from this link sir https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem:

`android:selectedItemPosition` is triggered whenever an item is selected (this doesn't implicitly include that the item is clicked/checked.

Using `android:selectedItemPosition` as a two-way data binding in a `ListView` doesn't actually automatically triggered when an item is selected, and therefore the LiveData doesn't get triggered.

You can see that when you create a normal `ListView` without any data binding; when you click an item, this won't trigger the selection, notice the below when an item is clicked (nothing get highlighted with a different color):

[image]

#### Solution:

In order to solve that for the sake of data binding, you need to explicitly do select the that item whenever it is clicked by registering `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView`:

```
binding.listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
    if (position >= 0) { // avoid -1 position calls
        binding.listview.requestFocusFromTouch()
        binding.listview.setItemChecked(position, true)
        binding.listview.setSelection(position)
    }
}
```

This way the live data will be set to the current selected position:

Notice when an item is selected, it's now highlighted with a light grey that is because the selection is enabled:

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity why ListView does not trigger the selection automatically?

Comment: I think they leave it to the developer, because the selection highlights the item, but not every case you want to select/highlight the items

Comment: @HussienFahmy Are you still confused of something?

Comment: No thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have not forgetten to set your binding lifecycleOwner in your fragment

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

Comment: I updated the question, yes i set it `NOTE: All other observes works well`